# How do I access arrays on the asm.js heap from Javascript code, when the array's type is not Uint8?

Tags: javascript, arrays, asm.js

I'm trying to use emscripten and asm.js in order to speed up my Javascript code. I need to get data from an `Int32Array` into my compiled C function. According to [this Github site](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html) I can allocate a buffer, copy data into it, and call a function taking that buffer's pointer as input, like so:

```
var buf = Module._malloc(myTypedArray.length*myTypedArray.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);
Module.HEAPU8.set(myTypedArray, buf);
Module.ccall('my_function', 'number', ['number'], [buf]);
Module._free(buf);
```

But it doesn't work for anything besides an `Uint8Array`, because `Uint8Array.set` "helpfully" converts the input array's data type to `Uint8` instead of just doing a raw copy. In other words, if I try to copy `Int32Array.of(1, -1)` into the heap at address 100 using this method, I'll get

```
{ ... 100:1, 101:255, 102:0, 103:0, 104:0, 105:0, 106:0, 107:0 ... }
```

instead of

```
{ ... 100:1, 101:0, 102:0, 103:0, 104:255, 105:255, 106:255, 107:255 ... }
```

(assuming little endian)

So how am I supposed to copy the data to and from the asm.js heap? I understand that an `ArrayBuffer` object can be bitwise-casted to any typed array type, but <s>it doesn't seem possible to do the reverse</s> (correction: see Jaromanda X's comment). Also, I read, considered, and rejected the website's suggestion to prefer `setValue` / `getValue` whenever possible because I have millions of things to copy and I'd like to avoid the overhead of one function call each if at all possible.

Comment: What is the expected result of `Int32Array.of(1, -1)`

Comment: see `Int32Array.of(1, -1).buffer` is `[1, 0, 0, 0, 255,255,255,255]` - does that help?

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for the correction; I'll construct a `Uint8Array` from the `Int32Array.buffer` and pass it to asm.js to solve my problem. I can't believe I missed that in the documentation. I think it's time to get some rest. Please upgrade your comment to an answer and I'll gladly accept it tomorrow. For others, here's the [relevant documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray#Properties_2) for `TypedArray.buffer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out I was wrong: it is possible to convert `Int32Array` to an `ArrayBuffer` and consequently to an `Uint8Array` view of the original array. Here's a complete example of a function that sums up an array of `int32_t` implemented as a JS function passing an array of `int32_t` to a C function:

#### sum.c (compiled to sum.c.js)

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

double sum_i32(const int32_t* ints, size_t count) {
    double result = 0.0;
    while (count-- > 0) {
        result += *ints++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

#### sum.js

```
"use strict";

const cModule = require("./sum.c.js");

module.exports.sum_i32 = function sum_i32(array) {
    // Convert to array of int32_t if needed.
    if (!(array instanceof Int32Array)) {
        array = new Int32Array(array);
    }
    // Allocate a buffer to store a copy of the input array.
    const ptr = cModule._malloc(array.length * 4);
    let result = NaN;
    if (ptr === 0) {
        throw "Out of memory";
    }
    try {
        // View int32_t array as uint8_t using the int array's ArrayBuffer.
        const u8view = new Uint8Array(array.buffer);
        // Copy it to the right position in the heap and call the C function.
        cModule.HEAPU8.set(u8view, ptr);
        result = cModule._sum_i32(ptr, array.length);
    } finally {
        cModule._free(ptr);
    }
    return result;
}
```